# There is an error in the value of the log outputted int

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, stackdriver

I am running Go application on GKE.
I output the JSON log in the application.
When checking the log with Stackdriver Logging, there is an error in the numerical value.

[image]

How can we solve this?

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Value struct {
    V int64
    S string
}

func log(num int64) {
    v := Value{
        V: num,
        S: fmt.Sprint(num),
    }
    j, err := json.Marshal(v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", uint64(num))
    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

Even I gcloud command, I noticed that there was an error in the value.
Is there an error on the Server side of Stackdriver Logging?

```
gcloud logging write projects/gcpugjp/logs/bignum --payload-type=json '{"num": 36028797018963966, "text": "36028797018963966"}'

gcloud logging read projects/gcpugjp/logs/bignum
---
insertId: 1f25wvtf1b5rsv
jsonPayload:
  num: 36028797018963968
  text: '36028797018963966'
logName: projects/gcpugjp/logs/bignum
receiveTimestamp: '2018-10-02T10:20:21.734286025Z'
resource:
  labels:
    project_id: gcpugjp
  type: global
timestamp: '2018-10-02T10:20:21.734286025Z'
---
```

Comment: JSON has no integer type; all numbers are represented by 64-bit floating-point numbers (a.k.a. double) . You cannot expect all `int64` values to be exactly representable as a double.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!
I processed JavaScript and started to investigate the layer where JSON's errors are coming out.
I edited the text, but I think that there is something wrong with fluentd's layer.